# DOM-like APIs for HTML string content inside a web worker 

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, jsdom

Is there any library that could help with html string manipulation inside a web worker ?

What I'd like to be able to do is, inside a worker, have sizzle-type selector tool that would allow me to do things like:

```
hString = "<div><img src='foo'></img></div>"
imgSrc  = $(hString).find("img").attr("src")   // foo
```

, without the DOM interaction.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want is a pure Javascript DOM implementation on which top you could run jQuery and fellows

One such implementation exists for Node.js

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

It can spoof DOM window object, APIs and such.

You could take the code, rip off the Node dependencies and try to apply jQuery on the top of that inside a web worker.

Comment: I already know about jsdom.  It's good, but a bit on the slow side and probably too much of a pain to try and make it work inside a worker.

Comment: Are there rationale why you would get anything faster?