# Shimming `window` and `document` in web workers

Tags: javascript, html

Are there solutions out there for implementing `window` and `document` objects in ways that don't utilize DOM after they're initialized but have compatible interfaces? They would be useful for using heavyweight libraries like MathJax in a web worker.

Comment: Related? [DOM-like APIs for HTML string content inside a web worker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703785/dom-like-apis-for-html-string-content-inside-a-web-worker). I am not 100% sure what it is you mean by "*in ways that don't utilize DOM after they're initialized*", so I'm not totally sure if that question is helpful to you.

Comment: Is the assumption that a non-DOM copycat method will be more efficient?

Comment: @svidgen DOM objects are inaccessible from web workers by design.

Comment: not really, MathJax needs to see your active DOM to determine how to size the elements correctly. Moving it into a webworker means it can't actually do its job at all.

Comment: @Mike I'm sure it can be tricked into thinking what I want it to think.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do DOM manipulation in workers:

1. Import a DOM copy in the worker (really bad performance),
2. Parse the "document string" into a new DOM (really bad performance) and
3. Send and receive DOM manipulation commands to the browser
   (best solution).

It may seen silly but all you need is to send the "DOM related function"'s arguments to the browser and return the result to your worker;